# simplfying github actions ci.yml for version testing

Tags: github, github-actions

My ci.yml for GitHub Actions has this line in it:

```
-   name: Make Tests Compatiable With PHPUnit 9+
    if: matrix.php-version != '5.3' && matrix.php-version != '5.4' && matrix.php-version != '5.5' && matrix.php-version != '5.6' && matrix.php-version != '7.0' && matrix.php-version != '7.1' && matrix.php-version != '7.2'
    run: php tests/make_compatible_with_phpunit9.php
```

My question is...  is there a way to make that simpler?

I thought `matrix.php-version < '7.3'` might work but it doesn't.

`matrix.php-version != ['5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '7.0', '7.1', '7.2']` obviously won't work because `matrix.php-version` isn't an array. After reading https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions I thought `if: contains(['5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '7.0', '7.1', '7.2'], matrix.php-version)` would work but that got me this error:

```
Unexpected symbol: '['. Located at position 10 within expression: contains(['5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '7.0', '7.1', '7.2'], matrix.php-version)
```

I tried `if: contains(fromJSON("['5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '7.0', '7.1', '7.2']"), matrix.php-version)` but that got me this error:

```
Unexpected symbol: '"'. Located at position 19 within expression: contains(fromJSON("['5.3', '5.4', '5.5', '5.6', '7.0', '7.1', '7.2']"), matrix.php-version)
```

Is what I had in my first code snippet the simplest that I can possibly make this or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: Try: `if: contains(fromJSON('["5.3", "5.4", "5.5", "5.6", "7.0", "7.1", "7.2"]'), matrix.php-version)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [`jobs.<job_id>.steps[*].if`](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions):

> When you use expressions in an `if` conditional, you may omit the expression syntax (`${{ }}`) because GitHub automatically evaluates the `if` conditional as an expression. For more information, see "[Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions)."

And, from [Expressions' Literals](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#literals):

> `string`: You don't need to enclose strings in `${{` and `}}`. However, if you do, you must use single quotes (`'`) around the string. To use a literal single quote, escape the literal single quote using an additional single quote (`''`). **Wrapping with double quotes (`"`) will throw an error.**

So, you need to use single quotes to enclose that array to pass as a string literal:

```yaml
if: contains(fromJSON('["5.3", "5.4", "5.5", "5.6", "7.0", "7.1", "7.2"]'), matrix.php-version)
```

The example under [`contains`](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#contains) function also highlights this:

```yaml
contains(fromJSON('["push", "pull_request"]'), github.event_name)
```

You might want to lint your workflow(s) with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/ to identify issues much faster. See the linting result of your current workflow [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJwtjz1vwkAQRHv/ihGNQcGGEEiEWxqERIIUUIoIWWd0yJdwH/LuJfn5WfuoXjE72jfeVQiR2uzLN1RlAGvinkAXHRVe8thEx7G4qT4bImIdKF0VcMrqCnv1rXGUA8LG26DYqOam8WG4xWF7ODnDWD8MFcBcK1y8Y2Ucja+dt7v3t9fx6DNflU/5FIJlwirhucdLOU94TFjk59FkCqu4M39laEPxozsy3k3uX2SAjGvDsIlmVgzrS3ITtfpX1GqJo6it+372D8cLUC0=).

Comment: What if I wanted to do the opposite of `if: contains(fromJSON('["5.3", "5.4", "5.5", "5.6", "7.0", "7.1", "7.2"]'), matrix.php-version)`? I tried `if: ! contains(fromJSON('["5.3", "5.4", "5.5", "5.6", "7.0", "7.1", "7.2"]'), matrix.php-version)` and got a `The workflow is not valid. While parsing a tag, did not find expected tag URI.` error for that specific line.

Comment: @neubert: That should work fine. See [here](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#eJwtj8sKwjAQRff9ims3VbT1WcVu3YjgA1RciJRUIo3apDgJ/r7TxtUZuHeGM0ZnqB2VwdMUlAWAlWQbAh+nKTacu8Jp6+K3aLI2Iitr8q0YWlQyw1a8JE5cIKxMVQurRPGWuChb4rA+nLWyWPbbFUA9MnRwN9oKpan7+Jhqc9zvutE1TJNpOABj5pF6zBsskpHH2GMS3qLeABFPUe9/mq35o7JuH6FhxVr53QuxT/5ln5xjxz7LhIfgB79ZSdk=). Looks like that error was generated from someplace else.